# read Rdata without heads in pandas framework

Tags: python, r, pandas, rdata

I would like to read a Rdata file in python and, more important be able to manage it adding date and index.

According to the "R" the file is like

```
 [1]  51.42683  55.16056  51.55766  56.49496  60.35126  60.00867  59.86904  60.33833  60.14559  64.40926  71.08281
 [12]  73.65758  69.71637  76.85003  67.86899  72.48499  78.47557  94.64443  89.55312  81.55625  90.06554  65.46467
 [23]  84.79299  86.40392  90.09126  94.63728  81.17445  69.41700  71.15074  70.79933  79.15242  65.02803  58.99836
 [34]  56.32638  50.73658  48.88498  54.27198  53.77287  55.77409  59.09940  55.26362  60.29990  51.63972  51.89953
```

I also apply the summary tool in R and I have:

```
summary(file)

 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  32.33   45.94   51.60   54.03   60.92  108.03
```

As a consequence I have no head or index column.

I would like to import it in Python. Consequently, I have applied both pyreadr and rpy2 but in both cases, despite I can read the file, I am not able to transform it in a pandas frame. Applying for example pyreader as:

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('AdapArimaX_AheadDummy_Hour_1.RData') 
print(result.keys()) 
df1 = result["df1"]
```

I get with result.keys:

```
odict_keys(['file'])
```

and an error with the second command.

I think because I have no heads in the original files. What could be the problem on the packages or in the original file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that I have found:

```
result = pyreadr.read_r(fn)
a = list(result.keys())
df1 = result[a[0]]
```